# retrieving username with find_by_id(comment.user_id).name not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, find

I'm trying to retrieve a user name to insert into a comment on a blog post using rails

if I use

```
<%= comment.user_id %>"
```

it will give me an id but if I try and retrieve the user then call the name it return nil class

```
<%= User.find_by_id(comment.user_id).name %>"
```

why is this not working

if I leave .name off it returns a space in memory.

```
#<User:000x00000182fe48>
```

Comment: You're getting an instance of User, so if .name returns nil, then the name is not set. Please post the code that sets the name attribute.

Comment: Assuming you have relations set up correctly, why not just `comment.user.name`?

Comment: why don't you use association so that you could do `comment.user.name`? Also have you tried `(User.find_by_id(comment.user_id)).name`? BTW it is a bad idea to call `find_by_*` methods in view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, the dynamic finder is getting confused by the `id` and is returning the (Ruby) object's `id` (i.e. `object_id`) instead of the record's `id`.

Try calling `User.find(comment.user_id).name` instead. Or, better: `comment.user.name`.

The above should answer your question, but what you really want to do is:

In the controller:

```
@user_name = @comment.user.name
```

In the view:

```
<%= @user_name %>
```