# Rails App - Object_ID Returning for User Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, comments, objectid

I am developing a simple blog app and am having trouble displaying the user name associated with a comment.

Comments belongs_to :posts and :users. Posts belongs_to :user and has_many :comments. Users has_many :posts and :comments.

The create action in my comments model works and stores the comments as expected with the post_id and user_id:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
  @comment.user = current_user
  if @comment.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    flash.now[:danger] = "error"
  end
end

private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
  end

end
```

I am able to access the user name via the console as expected with Comment.first.user.name which returns the users name. When trying to do this in the view, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Here is the view:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>User:<%= comment.user.name %></p>
  <p>Comment:<%= comment.content %></p>
<% end %>
```

When I remove the .name from the user in the view, the app displays what looks to be the object_id.

```
User:#<User:0x00000001f62830>
Comment:Test comment
```

I've tried resetting the database mentioned here: [Show username when posting comments in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434786/show-username-when-posting-comments-in-rails)

I've also tried to address the proxy_id mentioned here: [Returning issue in Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458375/returning-issue-in-commentactiverecord-associations-collection)

I'm not sure what else to try. Also, when I reset the comments table so there is no data in it, the app still displays:

```
User:  
Comment:
```

when it loops through even though there is no data in it. I think it has to do with the dynamic finder confused by the id, but I tried moving it all to the controller as mentioned here, [retrieving username with find_by_id(comment.user_id).name not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204420/retrieving-username-with-find-by-idcomment-user-id-name-not-working), and I still am getting undefined method errors. Any ideas? Appreciate the insight. I am not using a comments gem, am developing in cloud9, and am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: So you sure that all comments in database have user ? Check it in console. Maybe you have one comment without user and it crashed. Flush your database, create one comment, check in console, than in view.

Comment: I am using the delete_all method to clear the database. I confirm that no records exist and then use the app to create a record and am getting the no method error. I think it is tied to some sort of proxy_id that exists prior to any data, but I can't figure it out. Any other methods I should use to flush the database?

Comment: This is quite strange, @denys281. When I add in a restriction to the each loop, the name method works:                                                                       <% @post.comments(1..1000).each do |comment| %>. There are only six records in the database. If I remove the 1..1000, the name method errors out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in this post: [Using <%= render comments %> always outputs an empty partial, even if there is nothing in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191689/using-render-comments-always-outputs-an-empty-partial-even-if-there-is-n)

"The issue is that the form is above the <%= render @post.comments %> so there is an empty comment when you reach the partial for all the comments, even if there's none in database, put the <%= render "comments/form" %> below to fix this."